# Increment the value inside a list element

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm having one of 'those' days, and everything I'm looking at is just messing up.

I have a Die class (as in Dice) and I want to roll 100 of them, and count the occurrences of each number. Say, out of 100 dice, 40 were the number '6'.

The issue is, if I hardcode a if face_value == 1 type of solution - if someone changes the amount of faces on the die - I've got a bit of an issue - as it won't count them.

I thought the best way to account for this would be to make a list (which is the same size as the possible die faces) and increment the number inside the list on each occurrence.

**In short, how can I increment the value inside of each list element?**

```
diceList = [ Die() for q in range(100)]
```

```
import random

class Die:
    face_value = 1
    size = 6

    def getSize(self):
        return self.size

    def getFaceValue(self):
        return self.face_value

    def roll(self):
        self.face_value = random.randint(1, self.size)
```

```
def rollList(n):
    i = 0

    a = n[0].getSize()
    faceList = [0] * a

        for Die in n:
            n[i].roll()
            x = n[i].getFaceValue()
            print(n[i].face_value)

            #faceList[x-1] = 1+1
            #print(faceList)
            i += 1
```

---

I've re-worked it a little, and I've got a way of getting the answer - I'm not sure if it's a particularly good way of doing it though.

```
def rollList(n):
    i = 0
    faceList = []
    a = n[0].getSize()
    for Die in n:
        n[i].roll()
        x = n[i].getFaceValue()
        faceList.append(x)
        i += 1

    print(faceList)

    c = 1
    while a >= c:
        print(faceList.count(c))
        c += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rollList(n):
    a = n[0].getSize()
    faceList = [0] * a

    for d in n:
        d.roll()
        x = d.getFaceValue()
        faceList[x-1] += 1
```

Comment: I was struggling, because I put faceList[x-1] = 1+=1 instead of faceList[x-1] += 1. Thank you, very much :)