# Loop and extract window

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a function (or series of functions), that perform the following operations:

Having an input array(A), for each cell A[i,j], extract a window (W), of custom size, where the value 'min' will be:

> min = np.min(W)

The output matrix (H) will store the values as:

> H[i,j] = A[i,j] - min(W)

For an easier understanding of the issue, I attached a picture (Example):

[image: Example]

My current code is this:

```
def res_array(matrix, size):
    result = []
    sc.generic_filter(matrix, nothing, size, extra_arguments=(result,), mode = 'nearest')
    mat_out = result        
    return mat_out

def local(window):
    H = np.empty_like(window)
    w = res_array(window, 3)

    win_min = np.apply_along_axis(min, 1, w)

    # This is where I think it's broken

    for k in win_min:
        for i in range(window.shape[0]):            
            for j in range(window.shape[1]):                
                h[i, j] = window[i,j] - k                
                k += 1
    return h

def nothing(window, out):
    list = []
    for i in range(window.shape[0]):
        list.append(window[i])
    out.append(list)
    return 0

test = np.ones((10, 10)) * np.arange(10)
a = local(test)
```

I need the code to pass to the next value in 'for k in win_min', for each cell of the input matrix A, or test.

Edit: I thought of something like directly accessing the index of the 'win_min', and increment by one, like I saw here: [Increment the value inside a list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504532/increment-the-value-inside-a-list-element?rq=1), but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
N=4             #matrix size
a=random((N,N)) #input

#--window size
wl=1            #left
wr=1            #right
wt=1            #top
wb=1            #bottom
#---

H=np.zeros((N,N))   #output

def h(k,l):         #individual cell function
   #--- checks to not run out of array
    k1=max(k-wt,0)
    k2=min(k+wb+1,N)
    l1=max(l-wl,0)
    l2=min(l+wr,N)
   #---
    return a[k,l]-np.amin(a[k1:k2,l1:l2])

H=array([[h(k,l) for l in range(N)] for k in range(N)]) #running over all matrix elements

print a
print H
```